# Add confrim to input type submit

Tags: javascript, html, input, submit, confirmation

I'm trying to add a very basic confirm dialog to my input type="submit","reset" buttons. My code snippets look like this. This is for a class assignment.

Script (I put console.log messages to see if/where I'm getting failures)

```
<script>    
        function validate() {
            console.log("I am in the validate function");
            var response = confirm("Are you sure?");
            if (response = true){
                console.log("Ok was selected");
                return true;
                }
            else{
                console.log("Cancel as selected");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My code for my reset/submit inputs:

```
<div class="row">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validate()"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="validate()"/>
            </div>
```

They're formatted into a form with a big div container. So as it is right now, whether I click OK or Cancel, it carries out the buttons function. I only want it to submit the form, or reset the form if "OK" is clicked. So console always gets a message that Ok was selected, even if I hit cancel. I've only been learning JS for a about one day. I tried for other answers but couldn't find exactly this situation. I know I'm missing something simple, and appreciate any help.

Full code below:

> ```css
> /*CSS Styles Specific to the Customer Registration Page Will Go Here*/
> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cinzel+Decorative&display=swap');
>
> #logo   {
>     display: inline-block;
>     margin: 15px;
>     /*float: left;*/
>     height: 100%;
>     width: auto;
> }
>
> .footer { /*sets a custom font for my footer and automatically transforms chars to uppercase*/
>     font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
>     text-transform:uppercase;
>     float: right;
>     text-align: bottom right;
> }
>         
> *{
> box-sizing: border-box
> } /*Makes all boxes sized as border boxes (so they apply padding etc)*/
>
> input[type=text], select, textarea { /*makes all my input/drop down boxes have the same formatting*/
>     width: 100%;
>     padding: 12px;
>     margin: 8px 0;
>     box-sizing: border-box;
>     border: 1px solid #ccc;
>     border-radius: 4px;
>     resize: vertical;
> }
>     
> input[type=text]:focus { /*highlight the text input area of any clicked form field to similar to my logo color*/
>     background-color: #48e0bd;
> }
>
> label { /*adds padding around all tags of type "label" in my form*/
>     padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
>     display: inline-block;
> }
>
> input[type=submit], [type=reset] { /*applies color and other formatting to both reset and submit buttons*/
>     background-color: #2b8c76;
>     color: white;
>     padding: 12px 20px;
>     border: none;
>     border-radius: 4px;
>     cursor: pointer;
>     float: left;
> }
>     
> input[type=submit]:hover, [type=reset]:hover { /*darkens reset or submite button when I hover over them*/
>     background-color: #1f6656;
> }
>
> .container{
>     border-radius: 0px;
>     background-color: #f2f2f2;
>     padding: 20px;
> }
>
> .col-25 {float: left;
>          width: 25%;
>          margin-top: 6px;
>  }
>          
>  .col-75 {float: left;
>          width: 75%;
>          margin-top: 6px;
> }
>          
> .row:after{ /*clears floats after columns*/
>             content: "";
>             display: table;
>             clear: both;
> }
> /*Responsive layout for our registration page*/
>
> @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
>     .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit], [type=reset]{
>         width: 100%;
>         align-top: 0;
>         }
> }
> ```
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>Grainy Travel: Plan Your Escape Customer Portal</title>
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" /> <!-- This is a generic reset file off the web !-->
>         
>         <link rel="stylesheet" href="register.css" /> <!-- This is my custom CSS style sheet !--> 
>         <script>    
>             function validate() {
>                 console.log("I am in the validate function");
>                 var response = confirm("Are you sure?");
>                 if (response = true){
>                     console.log("Ok was selected");
>                     return true;
>                     }
>                 else{
>                     console.log("Cancel as selected");
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
>         </script>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"></a> <br /> <!-- have to figure out how to separate this logo from the table! Figured it out be removing float: left--> 
>     <!--this is a container that wraps my whole form field together. 
>     Each following <div /> wraps my form "entries" by rows split into two columns, a 25 and 75 width column
>     based on my register.css file. !-->
>     <div class="container"> 
>         <form method="post" action="bouncer.php">
>             <h1>Enter Your Information:</h1>
>                 <div class="row"> 
>                     <div class="col-25">
>                         <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
>                     </div>
>                         <div class="col-75">
>                             <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Your name..." />
>                         </div>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="row"> 
>                     <div class="col-25">
>                         <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
>                     </div>
>                         <div class="col-75">
>                             <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Your last name..." />
>                         </div>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="row"> 
>                     <div class="col-25">
>                         <label for="cadd">Street Address:</label>
>                     </div>
>                         <div class="col-75">
>                             <input type="text" id="cadd" name="cadd" placeholder="Your street address..." />
>                         </div>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="row"> 
>                     <div class="col-25">
>                         <label for="cname">Your City:</label>
>                     </div>
>                         <div class="col-75">
>                             <input type="text" id="cname" name="city" placeholder="The city of your town" />
>                         </div>
>                 </div>
>             <div class="row">
>                 <div class="col-25">
>                     <label for="prov">Province:</label>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="col-75">
>                     <select id="prov" name="prov">
>                         <option value="ab">Alberta</option>
>                         <option value="bc">British Columbia</option>
>                         <option value="mb">Manitoba</option>
>                         <option value="nb">New Brunswick</option>
>                         <option value="nl">Newfoundland and Labrador</option>
>                         <option value="ns">Nova Scotia</option>
>                         <option value="on">Ontario</option>
>                         <option value="pe">Prince Edward Island</option>
>                         <option value="qc">Quebec</option>
>                         <option value="sk">Saskatchewan</option>
>                         <option value="nt">Northwest Territories</option>
>                         <option value="nu">Nunavut</option>
>                         <option value="yt">Yukon</option>
>                     </select>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>                 <div class="row"> 
>                     <div class="col-25">
>                         <label for="postcode">Your Postal Code:</label>
>                     </div>
>                         <div class="col-75">
>                             <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="1N1N1N Format" />
>                         </div>
>                 </div>
>                 <div class="row">
>                     <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validate()"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="validate()"/>
>                 </div>
>         </form>
>     </div> <br />
>             
>         <div class="footer"align="center";>
>             Copyright 2021 &copy;
>         </div>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: You've to listen `submit` event on the form instead of click event on the submit button to prevent the form submission.

Comment: Right now you're setting `response` to `true` in your `if` statement because a single `=` is assignment. Use a comparison instead: `if (response === true)`

Comment: @Nick - So this fixed the functionality of the submit input, it now only submits if "OK" is selected, however input reset will reset the form whether OK or Cancel are selected. EDIT: Nvm I don't have return in the reset input!